# Remove Markdown links but keep link text and square brackets for normal citation using Lua filter

Tags: lua, markdown, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

I’d like to remove all markdown links but keep the link text and square bracket using Lua filter. For example, the original content is like:

```markdown
[@a-local-file, page 15](x-devonthink-item://742BD8FE-B962-422F-98C1-B1K4DQA5A117?page=15)
```

And I’d like to convert it to:

```markdown
[@a-local-file, page 15]
```

I’ve tried to write a Lua filter for this conversion:

```lua
function Link(el)
    if el.target:find("^x%-devonthink%-item://") then
        return el.content
    end
end
```

However, with this Lua filter, it returned only the link text:

```markdown
@a-local-file, page 15
```

There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72127544/19418090) but the answer is not very straightforward to my question. Because my purpose is to use
`[@a-local-file, page 15]` as `NormalCitation`. But if a pair of
square brackets is added, it will be changed as `AuthorInText`,
which is undesirable.

How to modify the code to keep both link text and square brackets for [Pandoc’s normal citations](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-citations)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not just add "[" and "]" to the returned values? something like "["..linktext.."]"

Comment: The linked question can solve my question, but I guess there is a more native way.

Comment: @TomBen no, what mourad is suggesting is the "most native way"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple trick is to wrap strings into tables, as pandoc will then treat them as `pandoc.Inlines` items and allow to concatenate them to the `link.content`, which is also of type `pandoc.Inlines`.

```lua
function Link (link)
  if link.target:match '^x%-devonthink%-item://' then
    return {'['} .. link.content .. {']'}
  end
end
```

Pandoc will treat this as if we had written

```
    return
        pandoc.Inlines{pandoc.Str '['} ..
        link.content ..
        pandoc.Inlines{pandoc.Str ']'}
```

Now, some formats use square brackets as part of their markup, and pandoc will escape them in that case. If the goal is to have unescaped brackets while round-tripping to Markdown, then we'll need to use `RawInline` elements instead of `Str`:

```lua
    return raw'[' .. link.content .. raw']'
```

where `raw` is defined as

```lua
local function raw (s)
  return {pandoc.RawInline('markdown', s)}
end
```

The content of `RawInline` elements is not escaped (if the raw format matches the target format).

---

#### Citations

The updated question mentions the desire to have this treated as a normal citation. This isn't quite as straight forward, because citation parsing isn't simple. What we can do, however, is create a Markdown string that looks the way we'd want it to, and then use `pandoc.read` to parse it into an AST:

```lua
    local linkstring = pandoc.utils.stringify(link.contents)
    -- alternative:
    -- local placeholder = pandoc.Pandoc{pandoc.Plain(link.contents)}
    -- local linkstring = pandoc.write(placeholder, 'markdown')
    local citationmd = string.format('[%s]', linkstring)
    return pandoc.utils.blocks_to_inlines(
      pandoc.read(citationmd, 'markdown').blocks
    )
```

Make sure that the filter runs before `citeproc`.

Comment: Thanks! This code get `\[a-local-file, page 15\]`, where square brackets are escaped. But it should actually be `[a-local-file, page 15]` for the use of citations. How could it be modified to make it?

Comment: Sorry I didn’t make my question clearly. The most important part of this Lua filter is removing links but keep link texts to use as the normal citation. I have updated the question. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it't the same result, all citations are treated as author-in-text citation instead of the expected normal citation.

Comment: D'OH, somehow I completely missed the part the part about `NormalCitation`. My bad. I'll try to update this later.